# Divide multiple columns in a data frame by adjacent columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset of the mean number of animals observed in a plot with a particular dominant tree type (column names are H or B for tree type and number for plot). They are in alternating order with all H columns before B columns, like below:

```
Survey<-c(1,2,3)
H1<-c(5,8,3)
B1<-c(6,3,9)
H2<-c(12,15,1)
B2<-c(3,17,8)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Survey,H1,B1,H2,B2))
```

I would like to to divide each H vector by the B vector to its right (e.g. the 5 in H1/the 6 in B1, the 12 in H2/the3 in B2), but my actual dataset has 49 columns and 9 rows, so I don't want to do this manually. Is there any way to divide every other column by the column to its right?

Comment: `df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Survey,H1,B1,H2,B2))` is incorrect and convoluted way of creating a dataframe. Use `df<-data.frame(Survey,H1,B1,H2,B2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) dplyr** Use across as shown:

```
library(dplyr)

ix <- seq(2, ncol(df), 2)
df %>% mutate(across(ix) / across(ix+1))
```

giving:

```
  Survey        H1 B1        H2 B2
1      1 0.8333333  6 4.0000000  3
2      2 2.6666667  3 0.8823529 17
3      3 0.3333333  9 0.1250000  8
```

**2) Base R** Using ix from above:

```
replace(df, ix, df[ix] / df[ix+1])
```

giving:

```
  Survey        H1 B1        H2 B2
1      1 0.8333333  6 4.0000000  3
2      2 2.6666667  3 0.8823529 17
3      3 0.3333333  9 0.1250000  8
```

Comment: Thanks! So that works for the sample dataset but my actual column headers are quite long and contain multiple Bs and Hs (e.g. mean_Carabids_MacLeish_4B(M)_2)). Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without relying on the letters in the column header? Also, I apologize for not including that in the sample.

Comment: I have changed the answers to use column positions rather than names.